# How to display square root if 50 as 5√2 in python

Tags: python, square-root

I am writing a program to output square root of an number in python. My current code looks like:

```
import math
num = int(input("Enter the number for which you want the square root"))

if math.floor(math.sqrt(num)) == math.ceil(math.sqrt(num)):
    v = math.sqrt(num)
    print(f"The given number is perfect square and the square root is {v} ")
elif num <0:
    print("The square root of the given number is imaginary")
else:
    print(f"The square root of the given number is \u221A{num}") 
    #\u221A is unicode for square root symbol
```

My current program checks if the entered number is perfect square then displays the square root. if it is not a perfect square it just displays √num. For example if num is 300, it will display √300. But i want it to display it as 10√3. Any ideas about how do i do that. I dont want any decimals in my result.

Comment: Split the number into its prime factors and find pairs of equal numbers in it! And BTW this is a community for software development, not math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the largest root that is a divisor of your number and present the remainder as the √xxx part:

```
def root(N):
    for r in range(int(N**0.5)+1,1,-1):
        if N % (r*r) == 0:
            n = N // (r*r)
            return str(r) + f"√{n}"*(n>1)
    return f"√{N}"
        
print(root(50)) # 5√2
print(root(81)) # 9
print(root(96)) # 4√6
print(root(97)) # √97
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sympy`:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)
sympy.sqrt(300)
```

Output:

```
10√3
```